# resignfirstresponder on a UITextView inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I am hoping if someone can help me resolve an IOS/XCode question.

I need to have a UITextView created inside a UITableViewCell, this UITextView has responds to a user click, upon which a UIPopoverController will be displayed so that a sub-UITableView is displayed (inside the UIPopoverController) allowing a user to select from a list of choices (lines of text).  After the user select the choice (one of the line of text), that line of text will then be displayed inside the said UITextView.  First problem I am having is that when the user click on the UITextView the keyboard gets displayed instead of the UIPopoverController. How do I go about disabling ie. calling resignFirstResponder so that instead of the keyboard displaying, I get the UIPopoverController coming up instead.  Would someone be kind enough to share similar codes? or point me to some sample of how this can be done?  Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following delegate method to detect when textView is tapped and show your popOverController accordingly, return 'NO' in the delegate method so that no keyboard will appear...

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
//  code to show popOverController 

 return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for upvoting the answer but if that solves your problem , you are also supposed to make it correct...